# Mootools 1.4.3 Background Fade Effect

Tags: css, background, mootools, fade, effect

So I have code to swap the background, the problem I am having is incorporating the fade effect into it. I have messed with it for a while now and I am just getting frustrated. So the code is there, see how you can hack this to work.

Mootools 1.4.3

```
.socialIconsFB {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: -20px 3px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 57px;
    background-image: url(XXXXXX/social_icons/facebook.png);
}

<div class="socialIconsFB"></div>


$$('.socialIconsFB').each(function(socialIconsFB) {
    socialIconsFB.addEvent('mouseover', function() {
      this.tween("background-image", "url(XXXXXX/social_icons/facebook.png)", "url(XXXXXX/social_icons/facebook_highlight.png)");
    });
    socialIconsFB.addEvent('mouseout', function() {
      this.tween("background-image", "url(XXXXXX/social_icons/facebook.png)");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that "tween" effects not work with "background-image" but work with "background-color"
I would try in this way:

HTML:

```
<div class="socialIconsFB">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.socialIconsFB {
        float: right;
        display: block;
        margin: -20px 3px;
        width: 48px;
        height: 57px;
        background-image: url(XXXXXX/social_icons/facebook.png);
}
.socialIconsFB span{
     margin:0; padding:0;
     opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);
     width:100%;  
     height:100%;
     background-image: url(XXXXXX/social_icons/facebook_highlight.png);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$$('.socialIconsFB').each(function(socialIconsFB) {
    socialIconsFB.addEvents({
         'mouseenter': function(){
               this.getChildren('span').tween("opacity", 1);
               //it could be: this.getChildren('span')[0] 
          },

         'mouseleave': function(){
              this.getChildren('span').tween("opacity", 0);
              //it could be: this.getChildren('span')[0]
          }
    });

});
```

Comment: In any case, "tween" working in this way: el.tween("property", val_end); or el.tween("property", [val_start, val_end]);

Comment: +1 correct - cannot tween between 2 image sources. tween is based upon Fx and Fx.compute - which provides an abstraction for creating multiple steps between numeric units.